# Login problem - I enter password and it just asks for the password again

Tags: permissions, login, password

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on an IBM T43 laptop.

I hadn't used the laptop for a few weeks and forgot the password so reset it using the info found on here but now after entering the password the screen just keeps asking for the password again ???

`ls -l /home` returns `dr-x------`

I can login OK as 'Guest' and use internet but cannot use my own personal login.

Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

there's a problem with your X server. try booting in failsafe mode, and install the appropriate binary drivers for your graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Welp.
This is all easier if you have experience with linux or have installed gentoo/arch before.

Essentially, you will be booting from a live cd and making grub boot from text mode.

Get a live ubuntu (or any other distribution's) cd and boot into it.
Open their file manager and find your system (usually found in **/media**)
Mount the live cd'd **/etc** /proc and **/sys** into the /media system boot.
Get in the command-line.

Now, you're going to use an editor of choice (*nano*, *vim*, *gedit*) to edit `/etc/default/grub`.
Make sure you use sudo.

You're going to want to find:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

And change `quiet splash` to `text`.

Save the file and do `sudo update-grub`.

### _

Next time you boot into linux, you will have a commandline.
I assume your problem has to do with drivers not working and deniying **X** the ability to start.

Try removing all of those drivers and reinstalling them.
(I recommed you try the open source drivers since they are way less likely to fail you)

Hope that helped you. :)